# Error while installing Bouncy Castle provider in EJBCA.

Tags: java, bouncycastle, ejbca

Hi!

I'm trying to access an EJBCA server via the provided web services from my java application. I am trying to run the following code snippet from the official documentation (http://ejbca.org/docs/adminguide.html#Using%20the%20Web%20Service%20API%20for%20Integration):

```
  CryptoProviderTools.installBCProvider();  
  String urlstr = "https://localhost:8443/ejbca/ejbcaws/ejbcaws?wsdl";

  System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","p12/wstest.jks");
  System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","foo123");  

  System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore","p12/wstest.jks");
  System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword","foo123");      

  QName qname = new QName("http://ws.protocol.core.ejbca.org/", "EjbcaWSService");
  EjbcaWSService service = new EjbcaWSService(new URL(urlstr),qname);
  ejbcaraws = service.getEjbcaWSPort();
```

However, the first line gives me a ClassCastException: `org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider cannot be cast to org.bouncycastle.jce.interfaces.ConfigurableProvider`. I have checked that the BouncyCastleProvider does implement the ConfigurableProvider interface.

More curiously, when i call the function twice (`CryptoProviderTools.installBCProvider()`), the second time around i get a `NoSuchFieldError`, with the following cause: `java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: SN`

Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: Hi Stan, this escaped my intention (I'm not monitoring the Bouncy Castle questions without crypto tag). The only thing I can think of is problems with the Java version itself. Could you display the versions of the components including the JRE and OS? Or have you solved this by now?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, I found this document "The Cryptoworkshop Guide to Java Cryptography and the Bouncy Castle APIs" at http://www.cryptoworkshop.com/guide/cwguide-070313.pdf

which says:
To install the provider at run time just add:
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

This also requires importing:

import java.security.Security;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;

If I check the providers I do see BC

```
    Provider[] myProviders = Security.getProviders();

    for (Provider prov : myProviders) {
        System.out.println("Prov:" + prov.getName());
    }
```

(requires importing import java.security.Provider)

but now I'm stuck when I try to get any info from ejbca I get the

Administrator is not authorized to resource /administrator. Msg: .

So hope that helps you.